# converting javascript code to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have following code of javascript for search function. It works well when written inside html/php file it self, however, when I try to add this in my jQuery file, it doesn't work anymore.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function findmatch(){
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }


        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ){
                    document.getElementById('search_result').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;                
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'php/search.php?search_text='+document.search.search_text.value , true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
 </script>
```

I tried replacing 'getElementById' with $('#') and few some ways. But didn't work. I want to convert in jQuery so I can manage/animate 'search_result' div according to size of result returned. I don't know how will I do that. But, if you can guide me fir that extra, It would be great/

Comment: Please explain "jQuery file" difference from "html/php file"

Comment: Just to point one mistake you possible made. The jquery `getElementById` equilevant is `$('#').get(0)` or `$('#')[0]`.

Comment: When you add the code to your "JQuery File" (I'm assuming it has a .js extension) Do you remove the html <script></script> tag?

Comment: I meant, I have a myScript.js file, which works according to jQuery syntaxt. I want to add above javascript code to that file, but when I do, it stops working. And I am not very familiar with XMLHttp etc for jQuery.

Comment: @DylandeStPern..yes I removed those tags.

Comment: You do realize that JQuery is written in javascript, Right?

Comment: jQuery **is** Javascript, so for Javascript to not work when placed in a "jQuery file" doesn't make sense. Your issue lies somewhere else. Perhaps the `.js` file is inside your `<body>` tag whereas your inline code is in the `<head>`?

Comment: And why would you like your code to run *slower*???

Comment: perhaps issue is somewhere else, I'm trying to get the solution. And using word "jQuery file" was just to confirm that it was written in jQuery syntax. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, it's Ajax call:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jqueryLibrary.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function findmatch() {
          $.ajax({
             url: 'php/search.php?search_text=' + document.search.search_text.value,
             type: 'get',
             success: function(responseText){
               $('#search_result').text(responseText);
             }
          })
       }
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this code, but didn't work, may be because problem is somewhere else or something like that. Glad you tried to help

Comment: well, all solutions were correct, I did a horrible mistake by forgetting to call the function on keydown. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
function findmatch(){
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : 'php/search.php?search_text='+document.search.search_text.value,
        cache : false,
        async : false,
        success : function(data) {
            $('#search_result').text(data);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Why `async: false`? And it must be `GET` request.

Comment: jQuery does not expose the `innerHTML` property of the original DOM node, you want either `.text` or `.html` method

Comment: ya i know but still it may work in some cases but i will replace it ,thanks for the catch its was done in hurry and all the copy paste work was not done wisly @PatrickEvans

Comment: depends on the requirement u may or may not @Justinas

Comment: Well, `xmlhttp.open('GET')` clearly shows `GET` method!

Comment: @PatrickEvans just edited my code you can up vote it if earlier down voted

Comment: I edited this because there was a left-over ' and here's an upvote because you actually accounted for the `errorThrown`

Comment: Tried this code as well, but didn't work. May be problem lies inside some other place. I'll update post as soon as I get it.

Comment: Sorry friends, these solutions where correct. I made a mistake of not calling function on keydown. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

So this should work:

```
function findmatch() {
    $.post('php/search.php?search_text='+document.search.search_text.value,function(response){
        $('#search_result').html(response);
    });
}
```

**//EDIT: Made a mistake, semikolon after function findmatch() { }; <<**

Greetings

Comment: I tried this code as well, but it didn't solved issue. Issue might be somewhere else. I will update post as soon as i find the solution.

Comment: PS: Look at the function above, made a mistake. Don't know if you've seen that!!

So you can just try to send the Search value via POST.
`function findmatch(search_text) {
$.post('php/search.php',{ Search_value = search_text }, function(response) {
    $('#search_result').html(response);
});
}`

Comment: This is correct solution, just it need to have 'get'. And it was my mistake that I didn't call this method on particular event. Regretting mistake. Thank you for help all!